# Is there a way to pass data from javascript layer to AppDelegate.swift without a plugin in Ionic Capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I'm using Ionic Capacitor (javascript application + ios/android native wrappers), and I have a situation where I want to get a small piece of data from the javascript layer and pass to ./ios/App/AppDelegate.swift.

Is there any way to achieve this *without* the use of a plugin? For example, can AppDelegate.swift "listen" for javascript events in a manner similar to how a Capacitor plugin would?

Thus, in my application, I would have a form field (e.g. for email), and then on button click I pass the string to AppDelegate.swift, which then does something with it.

Comment: Don't think so. Why the `AppDelegate.swift` specifically?

Comment: I'm using a library that needs to be instantiated and used within the main application thread, which for Capacitor happens in AppDelegate.swift

Comment: Whats the library?

Comment: @johnborges it's called "Appboy" - https://www.braze.com/docs/developer_guide/platform_integration_guides/ios/initial_sdk_setup/installation_methods/cocoapods/

Answer (score 0):

Plugin is likely your best shot.

Not sure which features of that SDK you're using, but you could try using the [Cordova plugin](https://www.braze.com/docs/developer_guide/platform_integration_guides/cordova/cordova_integration/) they provide. Capacitor [supports](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/cordova) using some Cordova plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.
It's documented [here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/core-apis/ios#triggerjsevent)
That not the favourite way, though.

Edit:
this is from native to JS in the doc, sorry about it.

- I checked a the module you want to install in your app, it seems you want to do it in AppDelegated because of the need of UIApplication.
- If it's that i recommend you to create a plugin and use it inside like [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/blob/249073d6edae594e6cf324cacbce9347fdaa4b53/ios/Capacitor/Capacitor/Plugins/BackgroundTask.swift#L7)
- Or last solution you can use a [config](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/core-apis/ios#config) if you don't need to change the config by deploy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It looks like that link to the Capacitor docs is meant to send native data to the Js layer, not the other direction.

Comment: You are right ! i dit my comment with other possible solution.